# Books for beginners on the Fourier Transform

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am a student who has just finished high school. I can easily handle IB level differentiation, integration and complex numbers.

I am interested in learning about the Fourier Transform. I am looking for a book, maybe one from a first year university course, which explains the Fourier Transform from the very basics, expanding the concept of Fourier Series and exploring the Fourier Transform from a mathematical perspective.

I read in some other forums that [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073039381) book was advised for beginners. However, I had trouble following the theory in the book. I feel like the book did not provide the solid background of the Fourier Transform I was looking for.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could advise me on a good book I could use.

Comment: A First Course in Wavelets with Fourier Analysis by Boggess is a very gentle introduction. The book alludes to some of the more advanced math concepts to satiate some of that curiosity, but it does not get bogged down in detail making it accessible to novices.

Comment: The book you reference has a description: "This text is designed for use in a senior undergraduate or graduate level course in Fourier Transforms." That would not be appropriate for someone finishing High School. What is "IB level"?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most elementary yet rigorous introduction to Fourier analysis is, in my opinion, the textbook [1] by Baggett and Fulks. Its strong points are the following ones:

1. Requires only a working knowledge of Lebesgue integration. This is a real minimum since Fourier analysis cannot be dealt efficiently with less advanced integration theories.
2. Deals with both Fourier series and integrals (and the latter both in the one and multi-dimensional cases)
3. Starts from elementary topics and proceeds up to very advanced ones: just to get an idea, in the last chapter Banach Algebras and the Gel’fand transform are introduced, while distributions are introduced in the preceding one.

Having understood the theory as presented in this book opens the understanding of more advanced treatises (like the ones of Elias Stein and coauthors).

**References**

[1] Baggett, Larry; Fulks, Watson,
*Fourier analysis*, Boulder, Colorado: API Anjou Press, Inc. pp. VIII, 183 (1979), ISBN: 0-88446-001-0, [MR0554082](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0554082), [Zbl 0437.42001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0437.42001)

Comment: The book you have recommended sounds good, but it seems to be very old and as a result I do not seem to find it online. do you possibly have a link to a pdf of the book?

Comment: @user10764803 I am not sure if the book has been digitized: however, you can perhaps find one in [a library near you](https://www.worldcat.org/title/fourier-analysis/oclc/925013682&referer=brief_results). I found a cheap used copy on Bookfinder a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I read mostly Springer books. You can try "Classical Fourier Analysis".

However, I do not think one book is ever sufficient to learn a subject thoroughly. Read also books about linear algebra as they explain concept about orthonormal basis, which is important for discreet Fourier transform. Do not hesitate to research from other sources including this website.

n.p. I always find it weird that most schools teach Fourier transform first and then its inverse (some of them do not teach the inverse at all). I learned inverse Fourier first and it made me understand better why we use Fourier transform.

Comment: Is the author of the book you are referring to "Loukas Grafakos"?